# Variables in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I want to insert a directory with multiple text files into a SQL database. Because I have multiple files, I want to use a loop that gets all files one by one. I'm having trouble with using variables in my query. Below is my query:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @file AS nvarchar(MAX)

WHILE(@i<=50)
BEGIN
  SET @file = 'C:\Users\Barry\Desktop\Output\output' + cast(@i as varchar(2)) + '.txt';
  INSERT INTO dbo.Table
  SELECT book.*
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK (@file), SINGLE_CLOB) as j
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
  WITH (Id int N'$.id', BookId int N'$.book_id') AS book
  SET @i = @i +1;
END
```

Example names of the files: output1.txt, output2.txt and so on.

I have used this 
[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/07/bulk-importing-json-files-into-sql-server/)

I get an error on following row:

```
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK (@file), SINGLE_CLOB) as j
```

Error message: Cannot bulk load. The file "@file" does not exist.
I'm using SQL server 2016

Comment: And do all 50 files actually exist?

Comment: Are the files in the Desktop of the same machine running SQL Server?

Comment: Can you share the sample file path with the exact file name for example?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, they exist. I'm sure of that.

Comment: @Juan Yes, they are on the same machine

Comment: Have you tried the UNC path instead? Instead of doing the insert, just print all 50 and make sure your loop runs first. Side note, i'm 99% sure you have to make that OPENROWSET dynamic SQL...

Comment: @asktonishant I edited the exact file path and added the names of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with Dynamic SQL since you are using parameters in your `OPENROWSET`

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @file AS nvarchar(MAX)

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

WHILE(@i<=50)
BEGIN
  SET @file = 'C:\Users\Barry\Desktop\Output\output' + cast(@i as varchar(2)) + '.txt';

  SET @sql = '
  INSERT INTO dbo.[Table]
  SELECT book.*
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @file + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
  WITH (Id int N''$.id'', BookId int N''$.book_id'') AS book'

  EXEC(@sql)

  SET @i = @i +1;
END
```

Comment: I get the following error on the row: WITH (Id int N'$.id', BookId int N'$.book_id') AS book'  
Incorrect syntax near '$.'.

Comment: i forgot to escape that... check it now

Comment: After escaping, I get multiple syntax errors in the @sql block.

Comment: Do print @SQL first, paste it in and see what error you get then adjust

Comment: I see what it was, i forgot quotes for filename... edited now sot hat `@file` is quoted too @BarryStotter

Comment: I have copied your query and it won't work. I still get Incorrect syntax errors. The first one is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Comment: well is your table named Table @BarryStotter? If not, you have to change that to the actual table name.... the command that's getting ran is `INSERT INTO dbo.Table    SELECT book.*    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ('C:\Desktop\Output1.txt'), SINGLE_CLOB) as j    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)    WITH (Id int N'$.id', BookId int N'$.book_id') AS book`. You had it as dbo.Table in your code. If this statement will not work by itself, it won't work in a loop. Make sure that you can do a single insert first. However, for all 50 you'll need dynamic sql whcih is what i have provided based on your code.

Comment: @scsimon Yes, that is my table name. It's a stupid name, but only for testing purposes. I will try out the statement you posted.

Comment: @BarryStotter that's a terrible table name and is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server, therefore it needs [] around it. See my edits

Comment: @scsimon It works now! Thank you very much! I had to delete the brackets around:  ''' + @ file + '''. So it becomes this: FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @ file + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j. Can you edit your answer?